# VB.NET: What do I need for creating a chat application for my forums?

Tags: vb.net, chat

I own an online forum:
A host server with MySQL database support, domain name, and, MyBB forum software.

I want to create an application that will let my users log in, and, well, chat.

But I am clueless. What do I need? I have my own database online and host and everything so... What is a good start?

Comment: "But I am clueless" - really?

Comment: Yeah, really. You don't have to be specific, you just have to tell me a good place to start and I work from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order not to reinvent the wheel I'd suggest you to use one of existing solutions. For example [this one](https://blueimp.net/ajax/) (AJAX chat application. Built on top of PHP and MySQL).

Also there seem to be a chat module for MyBB forum. [Read more](http://www.123flashchat.com/mybb-chat.html).

-- Pavel